# I want to send a string from multithreaded server only the first time a client connected

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, java-server

i have developed a multithreaded server that is working good! **but now i want to make it send for first time that a client connects a string** and then continue with the same regular process recieving a string and sending a file! 
here is my code for the server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the stream Server");
System.out.println("listening to Clients");
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(3248);
        while (true) {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            if (connectionSocket != null) {
                Client client = new Client(connectionSocket);
                client.start();

            }
        }
    }
}

class Client extends Thread {
    private Socket connectionSocket;


    public Client(Socket c) throws IOException {
        connectionSocket = c;
    }

    public void run() {

        String path = "C:/pao/new2/";

        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();


        try {

            String fileToSendStr = readFile();
            File fileToSend = null;
            for (File f : listOfFiles)

            {

                if (f.getName().equals(fileToSendStr)) {
                    fileToSend = f;
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Connecting to Client to recieve the part " +fileToSendStr);
            if (fileToSend == null) {

            }
            System.out.println("Sending the chunk to Client");
            long length = fileToSend.length();
            byte [] longBytes = new byte[8];
            ByteBuffer bbuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(longBytes);
            bbuffer.putLong(length);
            connectionSocket.getOutputStream().write(longBytes);

            BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedInputStream bain = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToSend));

            byte buffer [] = new byte [1024];
            int i = 0;
            while((i = bain.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0){
                bout.write(buffer, 0, i);

            }
            System.out.println("chunk sended");
            bout.close();
            bain.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String readFile() throws IOException {

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        return r.readLine();

    }
}
```

the part of the client that want to make the connection is different than the part it makes that connection. only want to retrieve a string for first time and then that part is not accesible any more!

Answer (score 0):

`ServerSocket.accept()` is a blocking method. It will not return if a connection was not estabilished or a timeout (previously set) ocurred.

Put the server code in a separate thread of the instantiation of the clients, or put a timeout for the socket:

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(3248);
welcomeSocket.setSoTimeout(2000); // waits 2 seconds for a client.
while (true) {
    (new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            if (connectionSocket != null) {
                Client client = new Client(connectionSocket);
                client.start();
            }
          }
      })).start();
      try {
          welcomeSocket.accept();
      } catch(Exception e) {
          //socket timeout.
      }
}
```

Comment: by puting a timeout to welcomeSocket what i will earn! to go outside of the loop? but then i will need to start again the server!

Comment: Yes, it will throw an exception. You need to catch it. Besides it, you should really separate the thread you accept connections from clients of the thread you create clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it well, but you say that currently the server is running well and can serve clients. What you want is to know if a client is already connected before? The communication between your server and client spans through multiple connections?

This would require conceptual thinking.
If you were in HTTP land, this would mean some kind of session and/or cookie concept. With the cookie the server could store information on the client side (last time the client connected, some kind of state). With a session id you could keep track of what state are you in during the communication with the client.

In your case you may need to develop a very simple application level protocol (top of the ISO/OSI network stack). So for example after the connection established the client would send a byte to the server telling stage where the information exchange at, then the server would react according to that. At the end of the communication this "state" parameter would be updated, revised.

Does that help?

Comment: Look the client is coming now and sending as you can see a string and then recieving a file!! i want the client when connects don't connect to send but connect for recieve a string only the first time! after that connect and do what it have to do!

Comment: I think this is still a conceptual dilemma. How the server supposed to know, that a certain client now only wants to read? It has to know from somewhere. Somewhere the history/stage of the previous communication session with a client should be persisted and examined. As far as I can understand. Other than that TCP sockets are full-duplex communication channels. It's upon the client and the server themselves to decide and negotiate when and who will send and receive data through that "pipe".